# CSS Dropdown menu not working?

Tags: html, css

I've been following this video online on how to create dropdown menu using css. I followed it and there's no any signs of a dropdown menu on my website. It's so frustrating because i want to get over with it so i can focus now on backend dev. Hope you guys can figure this one out.

Code for html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE>
  <html lang="en">
 <head>
<title>MUSIC STORE</title>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.bxslider.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="../Music Store/img/rockSign.png"/>
 </head>

 <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header id="main_header">
            <div id="callout">
                <h2>&#9742; 111222333</h2>
                <p>Michigan State Kawasaki Iceland</p>
            </div>
            <h1>MUSIC STORE</h1>
        </header>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <nav id="nav_menu">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">INSTRUMENTS</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">ELECTRIC GUITARS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">BASS GUITARS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">DRUMS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">AMPLIFIERS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FEATURED ARTISTS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script><!--For Image   Slider-->
        <div class="slide-wrap">
            <div class="slider">
                <ul class="slider1">
                    <li><img src="../Music Store/img/ibanez.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img src="../Music Store/img/raven.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img src="../Music Store/img/metallica.jpg"/></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.slider1').bxSlider({
            mode: 'fade',
            captions: false,
            auto:true,
            pager:false,

            });
        $('.slider2').bxSlider({
            pager:false,
            captions: true,
            maxSlides: 3,
            minSlides: 1,
            slideWidth: 230,
            slideMargin: 10
            });
        $('.slider3').bxSlider({
            mode: 'fade',
            captions: false,
            auto:true,
            pager:false,
            controls:false,
            });
        </script>       


        <section class="one-third">
            <div class="border_section">
                <h3>NEW BASS AMPS THIS YEAR</h3>
                <img src="../Music Store/img/fender_amps_bassbreaker.jpg"/>
                <p>We would like to proudly announce the new shipment of fender bass amps that you all have been
                waiting for. It will provide you that rich rock and roll tone like no other. Please check
                out our bass amp section for more details.</p>
            </div>

        </section>

        <section class="one-third">
            <div class="border_section">
                <h3>NEW FEATURE ARTIST</h3>
                <img src="../Music Store/img/feature_markHolcomb.jpg"/>
                <p>Behold Mark Holcomb from Periphery is in the house! Check out his info and new signature guitar
                at our feature artists section. He will also be having a 20-minute guitar clinic on Oct 8 2016 right
                here at Music Store.</p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="one-third">
            <div class="border_section">
                <h3>ATTENTION VOCALISTS!</h3>
                <img src="../Music Store/img/GoMic.jpg"/>
                <p>Check out the new Samson Go Mic Connect. It has a top-notch noise cancellation feature that can 
                definitely minimize the annoying sound that your dog makes while your recording. For more details, 
                Go to Accessories section.</p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <footer>
            <p>&copy;All Rights Reserved</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Code for CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Black+Ops+One:400,700);    /*--- Header --*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700); /*---        Navigation --*/

*
{
margin: 0;
border: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body
{
background-image: url('../Music Store/img/background.png');
background-repeat: repeat-x;

}

.clearfix
{
clear:both;
}

#wrapper
{
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1120px;
overflow: auto;     
border: 1px solid black;
}

#main_header
{
width: 100%;
font-family: 'Black Ops One', sans-serif;
background-color: black;
border: 1px solid black;
color: white;
}

#main_header h1
{
float: left;
font-size: 380%;
margin: -10% 0 0 2%;

}

#callout
{
margin: 50px 20px 0 0;
}

#callout h2{
text-align: right;
color: white;
}

#callout p{
text-align: right;
padding: 0%;
color: grey;
font-size: 20px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
}

#nav_menu
{

width: 100%;
height: 10%;
background-color: white;
}

#nav_menu li
{
display: inline-block;
margin: 20px 20px 20px 63px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
}

#nav_menu li a
{
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}

#nav_menu li a:hover
{
color: grey;
}

.sub-menu
{   
position: absolute;
background-color: black;
list-style-type: none;
width: 124px;
padding-left: 0px;
margin-left: -25px;
padding-top: 5px;
opacity: 0;
}

.sub-menu li
{
padding-left: 25px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#nav_menu li:hover .submenu
{
opacity: 1;
}

.sub-menu li:hover
{
color: green;
background-color: yellow;
}

 /*--- Start Image Slider --*/
 .slider{
max-width: 1120px;
box-shadow: 1% 2% 5% 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}

.slider1 img{
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider .bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a{
outline: 0 none;
position: absolute;
text-indent: -9999px;
top: 40%;
height: 71px;
width: 40px;
z-index: -1;
transition: all 0.7s;
}

.slider .bx-wrapper:hover .bx-controls-direction a{
z-index: 5;
}

.slider .bx-wrapper .bx-prev{
background: url("../Music Store/img/arrow_left.png") no-repeat 7px 9px;
left: 0px;
}

.slider .bx-wrapper .bx-prev:hover{
background:  url("../Music Store/img/arrow_left.png") no-repeat 8px 15px;
}

.slider .bx-wrapper .bx-next{
background:  url("../Music Store/img/arrow_right.png") no-repeat 10px 12px;
right: 0px;
}

.slider .bx-wrapper .bx-next:hover{
background:  url("../Music Store/img/arrow_right.png") no-repeat 10px 17px; 
}

/*--- End Image Slider --*/

.one-third img{
text-align: center;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
opacity: 0.9;
}

 .border_section p{
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
padding: 2%;
color: white;
text-align: justify;
}

.border_section h3
{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1%;
}

.border_section
{
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: black;
}


.one-third{
width: 27.35%;
float: left;
margin: 2% 0 3% 4.5%;
text-align: center;
background-color: white;
}

footer{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
height: 6%;
background-color: black;
overflow: auto;
}

footer p
{
margin-top: 1%;
color: white;
}
```

Comment: Seriously? -3?? lol! got alot of hate from css freaks here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS :
It will help you to have the result you want. Of course there are still adaptations to do regarding your preferences.

```
/* Without this line, the submenu elements are black on black background */
#nav_menu .sub-menu li a {
    color: #fff;
}
/* With this line you will remove the opacity:0; of the submenu when you hover the parent li */
#nav_menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    opacity: 1;
}
/* Don't set a width so you have a better output */
#nav_menu li .sub-menu  {
    width: auto;
}
/* This lines make the submenu li dislay verticaly and not inline */
#nav_menu li .sub-menu li  {
    display: block;
}
```

**Edit:**

Instead of changing the `opacity` property to show/hide the submenu, you should use the `display` property.
Currently, the submenu is just transparent, but always opened. If your menu were bigger in height, you could open it by hovering the mouse on the slide at the location where it is when opened.
By using the `display` property, you're actually hiding it, and it will be opened only if you hover the menu element (as it should be).

To do this, you have to replace the `opacity: 0;` in your `.sub-menu` class by : `display: none;`

Then change the code `opacity: 1;` in the `#nav_menu li:hover .sub-menu` by : `display: block;` (in the code I gave you before).

It will be cleaner than handling it with the `opacity`.

Comment: this does it. finally!

Comment: One more question tho, the dropdown menu is right behind my image slider. What code can i add so that the dropdown menu is on top of the image slider?

Comment: I can't tell you exactly as I can't see a working example of your website, but I guess the javascript slider is adding some `z-index` somewhere in the slides. You should try adding a `z-index` inside the `.sub-menu`.
Another point, you should handle the dropdown menu differently, I will explain it editing the answer.

Comment: Got it finally for real! Your right z-index is the missing piece.